# run two commands in screen detached

Tags: shell, gnu-screen, wget

I am trying to download a file with `wget` but in background and inside a screen that detaches ...

My initial command was:

```
wget http://www.example.com/file.zip -O temp/file.zip; mv temp/file.zip downloads/file.zip;
```

That would nicely move file once downloaded, preventing me from handling `downloads/` files while they still download in background.

Now I need to run that in backgorund with screen, so I run and detach it:

```
screen -dm wget http://www.example.com/file.zip -O temp/file.zip;
```

But how can I still pass the move command and so that it runs when first one is completed ?

**Edit:** I tried quotes based on DopeGhoti's answer:

```
 screen -dm 'wget http://mirror.leaseweb.com/speedtest/100mb.bin -O 1.bin; mv 1.bin 2.bin'
 cannot identify account 'wget http:'.
```

and this:

```
 screen 'wget http://mirror.leaseweb.com/speedtest/100mb.bin -O 1.bin; mv 1.bin 2.bin'
 cannot exec 'wget http://mirror[...] no such file or directory
```

**Edit:** I tried with full `/usr/bin/wget` and `/usr/bin/mv` paths, it complains about missing session name, I gave it session name with `-S foo`, now it exits silently, no such screen to resume and no files downloaded:

```
screen -dm -S foo '/usr/bin/wget http://mirror.leaseweb.com/speedtest/100mb.bin -O 1.bin; /usr/bin/mv 1.bin 2.bin'
```

Comment: use `screen -dm bash -c 'wget http://mirror... && mv 1.bin 2.bin'`

Comment: @meuh worked great, if you want to add it as an answer, I would accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It works if I specify **bash -c**

```
screen -dm bash -c 'command1; command2;'
```

User ***meuh*** provided this solution in comments, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Put the entire sequence of commands you're sending to `screen` in quotes; otherwise the first semicolon ends that command and sends the remainder to the shell in which you're invoking `screen`:

```
screen -dm 'wget http://www.example.com/file.zip -O temp/file.zip; mv temp/file.zip downloads/file.zip'
```

It might, though, be wise to only do the file move if the download is successful:

```
screen -dm 'if wget http://www.example.com/file.zip -O temp/file.zip; then mv temp/file.zip downloads/file.zip; fi'
```

Comment: I added details to the question;  
I tried the commands and I am getting errors with and without -dm, it reacts strange.

Comment: You need to add a `bash -c` as screen wont run the shell by default. (see my comment on original post).