# Screen signal main terminal that it's finished and closed

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, signals

Referring to [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377808/run-two-commands-in-screen-detached) about running script in screen session in the background and closes itself.

```
screen -dmS myscreen bash -c 'command1; command2;'
```

How can we signal the main terminal that the screen myscreen has completed executing so that I can notify users ? Otherwise it will just silently finish and close.

Comment: Do you just want something like `screen ... existing ...; echo Done`?

Comment: Could you elaborate ? If I **echo Done** it will be printed right away irrespective of the screen. Try **screen -dmS myscreen bash -c 'sleep 1m'; echo Done**. Main terminal echo Done right away without waiting for screen to finish.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `screen -dm`, it starts a detached session, independent of your current shell. Since the new session is not a child of your current shell, you'll need to investigate its status yourself with some sort of busy-check loop.

One option would be to investigate the output of `screen -ls myscreen` and compare it with "No Sockets found in..." (as contrasted with the currently-running output of "There is a screen on ... (Detached) ... 1 Socket in ..."). This assumes that you'll only ever have one "myscreen" session running:

```
while ! screen -ls myscreen | grep -q 'No Sockets found in'; do sleep 1; done
```

The `screen -ls` command just parses out what's in the socket directory; you could look there yourself. The socket file is generically placed in `$SCREENDIR`; on the system I tested with, `SCREENDIR=/var/run/screen`. The loop below will succeed as long as there is at least one file matching the wildcard and will exit when no such files exist any more:

```
while ls /var/run/screen/S-"$LOGNAME"/*.myscreen > /dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done
```

This still relies on the assumption that you've only started one screen session named "myscreen".

If you might start more than one session with the same name, you'd have to be more careful to pick out the PID corresponding to each session.